# Force UIWebView to load mobile version of website, like Safari does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm making an app where having a `UIWebView` is absolutely necessary. However, I'm having a problem where the `UIWebView` doesn't load the mobile version of the website.

I've read some questions on StackOverflow, and they all seem to say it's up to the website to decide what type to display, and that the `UIWebView` acts just like `Safari`.

However, I have tested with 9 different links to different websites and they all load the desktop version in my `UIWebView` and the mobile version in `Safari`.

[image]

What could I do to force the `UIWebView` to load the mobile version just like `Safari` does? Are there a type of headers I could send or cookies to set or anything that actually works?

Furthermore, the desktop versions scale terribly in my `UIWebView`. They do allow zooming, but when I release they all (the websites) reset back to the same position. And when I try to scroll horizontally, they just snap back into the original position, which leaves the website impossible to read and my `UIWebView` utterly useless. If I can't force the mobile page, how can I make the desktop versions act differently?

Comment: It works for me. Maybe the constraints problem. What is the width of webview at run time?

Comment: @ntsh thank you! I forgot to constrain my `UIWebView` so the content was rendered wrongly. Your answer got me on the right path :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to set the constraints for the `UIWebView`, which caused the content to be rendered wrongly. I don't know how that's relevant, but constraining the `UIWebView` seems to not only render the content correctly but also display the mobile site.

Comment: Incredibly useful, thanks. In my case I was setting the frame to the containing view controller which was not yet laid out. I set the frame to the navigation controller's view's frame instead and it fixed it.